# How to remove strange encoding from pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following df:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"name" : ["a", "b", "c"], "value" : ['1\xa0412', 4, 2]})
```

I would like to replace '1\xa0412' with 1. I try this:

```py
df['value'] = df['value'].str.replace(r'\\.*', '', regex=True)
```

But it does not work. How can I solve it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```py
df.value = df.value.apply(repr).str.replace(r"(\\.*)|\'", r"", regex=True)
```

result:

```py
    name    value
0   a       1
1   b       4
2   c       2
```

but be careful because the column `value` is of type `object`. If you want another dtype you have to convert the column.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the unidecode library to process the data first, and then try to replace it. It worked for me for a similar problem.

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44539421/pandas-apply-unidecode-to-several-columns Does not work to me

Comment: Yes, but apply it to only those columns with the strange encoding. If it does not work - what is the error?

Comment: no error, but nothing changes. Try my reproducible example, please

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).